# No need to say 13 Ikkarim on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, prayer-book, faith-bitachon-emunah

Some people have the custom to recite the 13 *Ikkarim*, The Thirteen Principles of Faith, every day. A condensed version of them appears as the "Ani Ma'amin"s usually printed in a standard *siddur* after *shacharis*.

Someone told me their teacher said that there's no need to say them on Shabbos, as observing Shabbos is a fulfillment of the 13 *Ikkarim*. I think they said the teacher was using this to justify why it doesn't appear in the *siddur* after *shacharis* prayers<sup>1</sup>.

Is there any basis to this statement? It doesn't make sense to me. Perhaps it fulfills some of them, but I don't see what Shabbos specifically has to do with Praying exclusively to Hashem, or Moshiach, or Techiyas HaMeisim, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Although, neither do a lot of things...as it would be repetitious. A person can simply flip back to weekday *shacharis* and say all the extra things they want. Perhaps they were referring to the Artscroll Shabbos *Siddurim*, which don't have it. Although, they also don't have the Six Remembrances, and this explanation definitely doesn't address that omission...</sub>

Comment: **ירושלמי נדרים ג:ט**
אמר ר' אלעזר בי ר' אבינה מצוות שבת מליא להודיעך שהיא שקולה כנגד כל מצוותיה של תורה

Comment: [Tzitzis](http://shaalvim.co.il/torah/maayan-article.asp?backto=&ed=%E2%EC%E9%E5%EF%20%F0%E9%F1%EF%20%FA%F9%F2%E2%20&id=720) is also shakul keneged kol hamitzvos. What are you alluding to? :-)

Comment: Maybe you can skip the ikkarim if you're wearing tzitzis?

Comment: Sounds like a mistake. But usually when I say that, I am the one who ends up being mistaken.

Comment: There is Yigdal

Comment: @Russell, this would be a good answer/comment but we say Yigdal every day of the week and in case you are implying that some say it Friday night after maariv and that's in place of the 13 Ikkarim,, but we don't say the 13 Ikkarim then so how it is a replacement? So can you elaborate on what you meant to say?

Comment: In "עת רצון" siddurim after mussaf of shabbos, the שש זכירות are printed but the אני מאמיןs are not. Maybe this was the siddur their teacher had..?